# Help me find this Use Case story

Tags: user-interface, crud, use-case

I remember reading a how-to book several years ago, about Use Cases. (This was probably before user stories supplanted this part of the terminology.)

The task at hand was something like adding new customers.

There was roughly a 1-page offset section that described a couple developers who said something like "We don't need no stinking Use Cases. We do this all the time. Won't take more than a couple hours."

Next day they came back with your classic CRUD-type table maintenance screen - and were consequently chewed up in comparison to the UI developed from a good Use Case.

Anybody recogize this? It made a big impression at the time, and it's still a good cautionary tale. I'd like to find it again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain,  but it sounds vaguely like something from **The Inmates Are Running the Asylum** by Alan Cooper.